# Will ads appear without upgrading

Tags: android, admob

I am an admob publisher, and am able to display admob test ad in my android application using old admob sdk. If  I did not upgraded with new google admob sdk
 and release my application into market, will the ads displayed or not? Is it necessary to upgrade my app before going to release.
 I look forward to hearing from you at the earliest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i guess its the wrong place to ask...  try www.superuser.com

Comment: When a new SDK is provided it will usually include improvements and bug fixes.  For that reason alone I would recommend updating your code to accommodate the newest SDK before going to release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest upgrading particularly for the bugfixes and enhancements (e.g. faster load time).  However, you should be able to run with older SDKs, primarily because many apps are released and not updated through several SDK upgrades.

It's possible that you may not get priority for filling ads, but that's purely speculation.